# Datatable - Execute js code after pagination change

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify

My code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    my_func();
}

function my_func(){
    $(".my_class").css("background","red");
}
```

...seems that works only on displayed elements, but is not working on **hidden elements**, that are in the oter page of Datatable pagination.

[image]

My solution could be putting my_func() calling after the page-change. But how?

Other solution?

Comment: See the documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/event/page

Answer (score 1):

My first solution

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. If you're trying to add more information to the question please use the `edit` link under the question itself.